# Laravel data migration to new structure

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

We are planning a major database restructure and instead of "Create" all the migrations are "Alter"-ing already existing tables.

For example:

There's table `users` that holds a column, e.g. `role`.

After running migrations this column will be dropped and table "Roles" will be created with a `hasOne` relationship (just an example).

How should I approach converting the old data into the new structure as seamlessly as possible?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the environment you are working in. for example in production level you can't just move those values from one column to another because the database Is heavily under usage of customers. but for instance you can create a migration to only create the roles table. then create a new migration to copy the corresponding role of each row to the newly created table(roles).

### Roles

user_id | role_id

### Users

id | role_id

After moving the whole role_id from users table to Roles table then you can push the new code implementation.

I don't really like the idea of removing the role_id column from users table immediately. i would suggest to keep that column for a while till you finish the whole changes related to that column then you can remove it safety without worry about it.